# He do it or He does it?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is correct to say?

I wanted to say the my friend (do/does) one task on regular basis.

a) He do this on regular Basic.

b) He does this on regular basic.

Comment: None. *He* **does** *this on a regular **basis***

Answer (score 3):

Simple present tense, third person, no modal verb: Using "does" is correct.
Also, according to [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/on%20a%20regular%20basis) I would state that "on **a** regular basis" is the correct phrase.